# Rudin's PMA, Chapter 1 Appendix Proof of Theorem 1.19 Step 6 - Proof of (M4)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Rudin skipped the proof of Step 6.

I want to know if my proof of (M4) is correct. Thanks in advance!

The (M4) in the axioms for multiplication states that

> A field $F$ contains an element $1 \neq 0$ such that $1x = x$ for every $x \in F$. Now we are proving that $\mathbb{R}$ has this property.

In Baby Rudin, $\mathbb{R}$ is constructed from $\mathbb{Q}$ as follows:

> The members of $\mathbb{R}$ will be certain subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, called *cuts*. A cut is, by definition, any set $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$ with the following three properties.

> (I) $\alpha$ is not empty, and $\alpha \neq \mathbb{Q}$.

> (II) If $p \in \alpha$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $q < p$, then $q \in \alpha$.

> (III) If $p \in \alpha$, then $p < r$ for some $r \in \alpha$.

> The letters $p$, $q$, $r$, $\dots$ will always denote rational numbers, and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\dots$ will denote cuts.

> Note that (III) simply says that $\alpha$ has no largest number; (II) implies two facts which will be used freely:

> If $p \in \alpha$ and $q \notin \alpha$ then $p < q$.

> If $r \notin \alpha$ and $r < s$ then $s \notin \alpha$.

In addition, when proving Step 6, Rudin confine first to $\mathbb{R}^+$, the set of all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha > 0^*$.

> If $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^+$, we define $\alpha\beta$ to be the set of all $p$ such that $p \leq rs$ for some choice of $r \in \alpha$, $s \in \beta$, $r > 0$, $s > 0$.

> We define $1^*$ to be the set of all $q < 1$. It is clear that $1^*$ is a cut.

This is my proof of (M4):

If $r \in \alpha$ and $s \in 1^*$, $r > 0$, $s > 0$, then $rs < r$, hence $rs \in \alpha$. Thus $\alpha \cdot 1^* \subset \alpha$. To obtain the opposite inclusion, pick $p \in \alpha$, and pick $r \in \alpha$, $r > p > 0$. Then $p/r \in 1^*$, and $p = r(p/r) \in \alpha \cdot 1^*$. Thus $\alpha \subset \alpha \cdot 1^*$. We conclude that $\alpha = \alpha \cdot 1^*$.

Comment: "...hence $rs\in \alpha$. Thus $\alpha \cdot 1^{*} \subseteq \alpha.$" This doesn't follow directly from $rs \in \alpha$ but rather from the fact that if $p < rs$ then $p \in \alpha$ by $(II)$ . Of course you may have consciously omitted this step because you thought it wasn't worth mentioning, and that's fine as long as you understand this . Everything else is spotless :-).